# How could I find an orthogonal basis for $H^k$? - HELP!!

Tags: spectral-theory, eigenfunctions

Let $P^k=$homogeneous polynomials of degree $k$ in $x$, $y$, $z$, $k=0, 1, 2, \dots, $ i.e. $P^k= \text{span} \{x^{k_x}y^{k_y}z^{k_z} : k_x+k_y+k_z=k\}$ and $H^k= \{f \in P^k : \Delta f = 0\}$, where $\Delta$ is the usual Laplacian operator.

**Question :** Without using the spherical coordinate, if I give $P^3= \{x^3, y^3, z^3, x^2y, x^2z,xy^2,y^2z, y^2z,xz^2,yz^2, xyz\}$, what could be a basis for $H^3$ and why? I think I can use recursively the fact that $H^0=P^0$ and $H^1=P^1$, but I don't even know how. It seems like as $Δ$ is a linear map, and you have bases of $P^k$ and $P^{k−2}$, it is a linear algebra exercise to find a basis of $\ker⁡Δ$ in $P^k$. I think an excellent article for that should be [SPHERICAL HARMONICS AND HOMOGENEOUS HARMONIC POLYNOMIALS](http://www.math.utk.edu/~freire/m435f07/m435sphericalharmonics.pdf) page $5$, but I am not quite sure how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Orthogonal: you have an inner product in mind?

Comment: Yes, the $L^2$-norm.

Comment: So, an integral. How are you planning to make those converge?

Comment: Now that I think of it, there is a relationship between the global Laplacian and the Laplacian on the unit sphere; I will look it up

Comment: @WillJagy Polar coordinates. The radial derivatives are a separate term, so you have $\Delta_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} = (\mbox{radial}) + (\mbox{poly in }r)\Delta_{\mathbb{S}^n}$.

Comment: @Neal Could you explain the recursion with $H_0$ and $H_1$?

Comment: @JeanCharrue Rest assured, if I had time this holiday weekend after spending it with family and friends, I would work out the details of the answer and post it. As it stands, I may have time in the evening later this week if it has not yet been answered.

Comment: Ok thanks, but could you at least display or refer me an article about the basis of $\ker \Delta$ in $P^k$?

Comment: @Sharpie I have no idea why your account was suspended, but I and several other users have asked you to avoid excessive, worthless editing. By ignoring this plea, I am fairly sure that your behavior will continue to be noticed and, evidently, we'll start the cycle all over again. You should obviously just wait out the suspension, but as you apparently refuse to do so, can you at least be polite about it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can consider it a standard (but quite tedious) linear algebra exercise for any fixed $n,k$ (in your example, $n=k=3$).

More generally, the article you linked provides the following answer on page 3. Although it's not really clear what you mean by "finding a basis".

$H^k$ is the orthogonal complement of all polynomials of the form $|x|^2 P(x)$, where $P \in \mathcal{P}^{k-2}$. Here the inner product is 
$$ \langle x^\alpha,x^\beta \rangle = \alpha_1! \ldots \alpha_n! \delta_{\alpha,\beta}. $$

A nice proof is given in E.M. Stein's *Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions*. First, any polynomial $P = \sum_\alpha a_\alpha x^\alpha \in \mathcal{P}^k$ corresponds to a differential operator $P(D) = \sum_\alpha a_\alpha D^\alpha$, where $D^\alpha = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\alpha_1}} \ldots \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\alpha_k}}$. This correspodence is a ring homomorphism and in particular $(|x|^2)(D) = \Delta$.

Then the inner product in $\mathcal{P}^k$ can be introduced as 
$$ \langle P,Q \rangle = P(D) Q. $$
Check that this coincides with the previous one!

Let $Q \in \mathcal{P}^k$. From the identity 
$$ \langle |x|^2P, Q \rangle = P(D) (\Delta Q)  = \langle P, \Delta Q \rangle $$
we see that $Q \perp |x|^2P$ for every $P \in \mathcal{P}^{k-2}$ if and only if $\Delta Q = 0$.

Comment: I know that the link provides an answer on page $3$, but I'm not sure how to complete details. Could you edit your answer and explain to me?

Comment: What is it exactly that you don't understand?